# How to package a PostgreSQL extension as a binary .deb file in Ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-extensions

*What is the minimal-effort way to package a PostgreSQL extension into a `.deb` file for Ubuntu (as of 18.04)?*

I did some search but find many different suggestions (some outdated).

Suppose I want to package a simple postgres extension such as the [first and last aggregate functions](https://pgxn.org/dist/first_last_agg/doc/first_last_agg.html).

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25275227/683218) suggests that one should fist make a directory structure manually as follows:

```
ProgramName-Version/
ProgramName-Version/DEBIAN
ProgramName-Version/DEBIAN/control
ProgramName-Version/usr/
ProgramName-Version/usr/bin/
ProgramName-Version/usr/bin/your_script
```

and then `dpkg -b /path/to/the/ProgramName-Version` after setting the right file permissions.

Others suggest using [dh-make](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/07/14/using-dh-make-to-prepare-debian-packages/), and the [Ubuntu Packaging Guid](https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html) suggests a work flow that uses some toolchain based on `bzr`.

But I think PostgreSQL has its own build infrastructure for extensions called [PGXS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/extend-pgxs.html) (as of PostgreSQL 12.x). I found PGXS quite easy to use, because I don't have to worry the folder structure myself and `make install` will copy files to the right system directories regardless of the PostgreSQL version.

*Is there a way to combine the manual approach above and the PGXS approach to **automatically** create a PostgreSQL extension as a `.deb` file?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to combine the manual approach above and the PGXS
>   approach to automatically create a PostgreSQL extension as a .deb
>   file?

Sure. First you need to create a `debian/` directory with a `control` and `rules` files copied from other extensions. There are many examples in the [PGDG Apt repository](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt). Add the following line in your APT sources (bionic is the codename for Ubuntu 18.04) if you don't have it already:

```
deb-src http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main
```

To see the list of packages: `apt search 'postgresql-*'`

To download the sources: `apt source name-of-package`

Once your debian directory is good and the dependencies are installed, basically you build the package for the extension with `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b` like any other Debian package.